# How to create a Dataframe from a dict with the keys as header and the values as rows?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dict with emotions and their probabilities:

```
{'angry': 0.08,
'disgust': 0.0,
'fear': 0.16,
'happy': 0.05,
'sad': 0.02,
'surprise': 0.68,
'neutral': 0.02}
```

I want the emotions e.g, 'angry' as header, and the probabilities as rows. Does someone know how to make a df of it?

Comment: You should show what you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method. The values have to be converted to array-like before.

```py
import pandas as pd 

d = {'angry': 0.08,
     'disgust': 0.0,
     'fear': 0.16,
     'happy': 0.05,
     'sad': 0.02,
     'surprise': 0.68,
     'neutral': 0.02}
d = {k: [v] for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas.DataFrame() function like follow:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'angry': [0.08],
        'disgust': [0.0],
        'fear': [0.16],
        'happy': [0.05],
        'sad': [0.02],
        'surprise': [0.68],
        'neutral': [0.02]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Output:

[image]

Also, as correctly posted in other answers, if you want to adjust your dictionary into the correct format:

```
data = {k: [v] for k, v in data.items()}
```

[Pandas DataFrame documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
 'angry': 0.08,
 'disgust': 0.0,
 'fear': 0.16,
 'happy': 0.05,
 'sad': 0.02,
 'surprise': 0.68,
 'neutral': 0.02
}
pd.DataFrame(data=[d.values()], columns=d.keys())
```

Result:

```
   angry  disgust  fear  happy   sad  surprise  neutral
0   0.08      0.0  0.16   0.05  0.02      0.68     0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass for each `key` in your `dict` a list of values:

```
{'angry': [0.08],'disgust': [0.0],'fear': [0.16],'happy': [0.05],'sad': [0.02],'surprise': [0.68],'neutral': [0.02]}
```

Then you can simply use `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'angry': [0.08],'disgust': [0.0],'fear': [0.16],'happy': [0.05],'sad': [0.02],'surprise': [0.68],'neutral': [0.02]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)
>>    angry  disgust  fear  happy   sad  surprise  neutral
0      0.08   0.0      0.16 0.05    0.0   0.68      0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Series and convert to DataFrame:

```
pd.Series(d).to_frame().T
```

or use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
```

output:

```
   angry  disgust  fear  happy   sad  surprise  neutral
0   0.08      0.0  0.16   0.05  0.02      0.68     0.02
```

input:

```
d = {'angry': 0.08,
    'disgust': 0.0,
    'fear': 0.16,
    'happy': 0.05,
    'sad': 0.02,
    'surprise': 0.68,
    'neutral': 0.02}
```